# Getting URL of InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova

Using InAppBrowser I wish to get the URL of the site the user is currently on, when he chooses to close the InAppBrowser.

Adding an eventlistener for the exit event doesn't seem to return the URL.

My first thought for a workaround was subscribing to the loadstart event, and getting the URL from there, thus always having the "most recent" URL. However this doesn't always fire when the user presses the back-button.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Using PhoneGap 2.8.0

Answer (score 7):

Using 3.1 it is fairly simple

you just add an event on load start. or load stop.

```
 var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
 ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert(event.url); });
```

see the cordova docs for more info [Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser)

Comment: Does this work in regards to when the user uses the back-button?

Comment: Cordova 4.x here, looks like `event.url` is undefined now :/... any other way of getting the url ?

Comment: @Michael: maybe the first comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18402823/2914140 will fix the situation (set a parameter `event` inside function()).

Answer (score 3):

`InAppBrowser` exits event which does not return an URL.
In order to capture the URL, you need to listen to the `loadstart` events.
Here is an example that works for me:

```js
//Open InAppBrowser on selected URL
browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(initialURL, '_blank', 'location=yes');


//WARNING: Events will only fire in the app, not if running in a browser
//Every time a page is opened in the InAppBrowser, store the URL
if (browser.on('loadstart').subscribe)
 browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((e: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
  if (e && e.url)
   url = e.url; 
 });

//When the InAppBrowser is closed, check and use the last viewed URL
if (browser.on('exit').subscribe)
 browser.on('exit').subscribe((e: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
  if (url)
   ...use the last viewed URL...;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

***Getting URL of browser InAppBrowser in angularjs, Ionic***

You can get the url of the Opened window view (browser) by using the event handling of browser (InAppBrowser)

As a example we are calling a twitter page and whenever the page change the url it will show the alert with the Url :

```
var twitterWindow = window.open("https://twitter.com/", '_blank', 'location=no');
                    twitterWindow.addEventListener('loadstart',  function(event) {
                        alert("Current Event : "+ event.url);
                    });
```

Here we use the "addEventListener" for handling the event of browser .

```
 window.open('local-url.html');                  
// loads in the Cordova WebView 
window.open('local-url.html', '_self');         
// loads in the Cordova webView
window.open('local-url.html', '_system');       
// Security error: system browser, but url will not load (iOS)
window.open('local-url.html', '_blank');        
// loads in the InAppBrowser
window.open('local-url.html', 'random_string'); 
// loads in the InAppBrowser
window.open('local-url.html', 'random_string', 'location=no'); 
// loads in the InAppBrowser, no location bar
```

To handle the events of the Browser we can use :

```
var ref = window.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_blank');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url); } );
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url); } );
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url + ' - ' + event.code + ' - ' + event.message); } );
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); } );
```

And to Close the InAppBrowser :

```
var ref = window.open('http://whitelisted-url.com', '_blank');
ref.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Leo's answer: everything works fine if pass `event` object as an argument to `loadstart` function.

```
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert(event.url); });
```