# How to get success or failure callback url on Pinterest

Tags: javascript, cordova, pinterest, inappbrowser

I am opening Pinterest URL inside `inappbrowser` to pin the image along with link and description.

```
var url ="http://www.example.com";
var media ="http://www.example.com/image.png";
var desc ="Testing with Pinterest";
var pinterest = window.open("http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/"+
    "?url="+url+
    "&media="+media+
    "&description="+desc+,
    "_blank", "location=no");
```

I need to close the `inappbrowser` automatically once the user pins the image successfully. So is there any way to get the callback URL after pinning the details on the Pinterest wall?

Comment: helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951865/getting-url-of-inappbrowser

Comment: Not sure, but I know Pinterest asks developers to use [pinit.js](https://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js) and you can then say `PinUtils.pinOne({url:url,media:media,description:description});`