# Ionic InAppBrowser Website - Open Twitter Link in the App if Installed

Tags: android, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have an Ionic App deployed to an Android phone, that opens a Website using InAppBrowser. On the Website is a button link to a Twitter profile.

Currently the Twitter button opens in the users default browser.

How can I make the button open the Twitter App if installed on the users phone?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser, public platform: Platform, private appAvailability: AppAvailability) {
      const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
          toolbar: 'no',
          location: 'no',
          zoom: 'no'
      }


     this.platform.ready().then( () => {

        const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create("https://awebsitewithfblink", '_blank', options);

        browser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url); } );
     })


  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: browser.addEventListener is not a function
TypeError: browser.addEventListener is not a function
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:74:21
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14976)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5134:33)
    at t.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:14916)
    at r.run (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10143)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20242
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at c (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:19752)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:20273
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:5125:33)
    at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15581)
    at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
    at o (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:7894)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16823)
    at p (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27648)
    at HTMLDocument.v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:2:27893)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Ionic version do you use so I will try to provide you the best solution :

**In Ionic 1 :**
You can simply do : `<a href="twitter://twitter.com/somePATH">`

**In Ionic 2/3 :** I don't know if the first method still work, never tried but this one should do it :

First : Install plugins

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser        // For open the app
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-appavailability     // For check if app is installed
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device              // For check which device the user use
```

Second : Import them

```
import { InAppBrowser, AppAvailability, Device } from 'ionic-native';
```

Third : Complete solution with check of device / if app is here :

```
launchExternalApp(iosSchemaName: string, androidPackageName: string, appUrl: string, httpUrl: string, username: string) {
let app: string;
if (Device.device.platform === 'iOS') {
    app = iosSchemaName;
} else if (Device.device.platform === 'Android') {
    app = androidPackageName;
} else {
    let browser = new InAppBrowser(httpUrl + username, '_system');
    return;
}

AppAvailability.check(app).then(
    () => { // success callback
        let browser = new InAppBrowser(appUrl + username, '_system');
    },
    () => { // error callback
        let browser = new InAppBrowser(httpUrl + username, '_system');
    }
);
}

openTwitter(username: string) {
    this.launchExternalApp('twitter://', 'com.twitter.android', 'twitter://user?screen_name=', 'https://twitter.com/', username);
}
```

> Source 1 : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/open-facebook-twitter-app-from-my-android-app/9757/3
>
> Source 2 : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-opening-external-app/77932/3

**EDIT :**

Since you want to do an action on InAppBrower Website, I found this code that can be usefull for you :

```
var twitterWindow = window.open("https://twitter.com/", '_blank', 'location=no');
twitterWindow.addEventListener('loadstart',  function(event) {
                        alert("Current Event : "+ event.url);
                    });
```

> Source 3 : [Getting URL of InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951865/getting-url-of-inappbrowser)

You just have to control this url and check if it's a Twitter URL. If it's one, you just have to do something like my previous answer.

Comment: Hi, I have already done something similar but is not what I am after. Let me explain further, your solution is for a button inside the Ionic App, however, the button I want to work with is on a Website on the internet that is not linked to Ionic. I am currently opening the Website using InAppBrowser inside the app.On the website is a link to a twitter page, I am trying to make that button open my app if installed instead of just the default browser. Thanks

Comment: @t3ch3 Does the website open your twitter app if you are using a random web browser ? I guess you can't control what is in an other website. But you might be able to detect when the url change and looks like a twitter url.

Comment: No it doesn't. I found a section about EventListeners in the InAppBrowser documentation that I am currently going over, maybe that will let me detect url changes.

Comment: thanks, using that and the documentation I coded something that looks right but I'm getting an error. Edited with code and error.

Comment: @t3ch3 try to replace your "const browser" by "var browser"

Comment: No, doesn't fix it.